# How to delete old duplicate rows based on 2 columns but keep the latest row?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, sql-delete

So I have this table (called test_table)

```
id  |  hotel_id  |  user_id
1   |  1         |  1
2   |  1         |  1
3   |  1         |  2
4   |  2         |  3
5   |  1         |  2
6   |  3         |  3
```

So if the hotel_id and the user_id is the same, then I want to delete the duplicate rows but keep the latest row (the latest row is the row with the higher `id`).

So after deleting my table would look like the table below.

I deleted `id 1` because there is a newer row `id 2`.

I deleted `id 3` because there is a newer row `id 5`.

```
id  |  hotel_id  |  user_id
2   |  1         |  1
4   |  2         |  3
5   |  1         |  2
6   |  3         |  3
```

I tried with the code below but it only checks if one column is a duplicate. What is the most efficient way to do this?

```
delete test_table
   from test_table
  inner join (
     select max(id) as lastId, hotel_id
       from test_table
      group by hotel_id
     having count(*) > 1) duplic on duplic.hotel_id = test_table.hotel_id
  where test_table.id < duplic.lastId;
```

Comment: Don't use `MAX(id)`. Do an `ORDER BY` instead. and you could probably leave one row behind by using `LIMIT COUNT(*) - 1`

Comment: Also, it is only finding it based on one column because you're only grouping on one column. Try `group by hotel_id, user_id`

Comment: @Anthony what do you mean don't use `max(id)` Could you show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.x (available since April 2018) you can use windows functions to identify the *obsolete* rows. For example:

```
delete from test_table where id in (
  select id
  from (
    select
      id, row_number() over(partition by hotel_id, user_id order by id desc) as rn
    from test_table
  ) x
  where rn <> 1
)
```

Comment: You should maybe note the release date for 8.x, as I'm guessing most stacks aren't on it yet, so this is almost an edge feature. (But a great one and I'm glad someone mentioned it)

Comment: @Anthony Added the release date.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way in MySQL uses a `JOIN`:

```
delete tt
    from test_table tt join
         (select tt.hotel_id, tt.user_id, max(tt.id) as max_id
          from test_table tt
          group by tt.hotel_id, tt.user_id
         ) tokeep
         on tokeep.hotel_id = tt.hotel_id and
            tokeep.user_id = tt.user_id and
            tokeep.max_id > tt.id;
```

If `id` is unique in the table, this can be simplified to:

```
delete tt
    from test_table tt left join
         (select tt.hotel_id, tt.user_id, max(tt.id) as max_id
          from test_table tt
          group by tt.hotel_id, tt.user_id
         ) tokeep
         on tt.id = tokeep.max_id
     where to_keep.max_id is null;
```